# Why my Application name is the same as Activity name?

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

Why is my app name "Money" instead of "My Application" ? What can I do to change it to "My Application"?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9buup.png

@string/app_name = My Application
@string/main_activity_title = Money

```
    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.money.list.MoneyActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/main_activity_title"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"/>

        <activity-alias
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/main_activity_title"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:targetActivity=".activities.money.list.MoneyActivity">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>
 </application>
```

Comment: The label shown in the launcher will be the label of the `intent-filter` that handler the `MAIN` action. If no label is set for the `intent-filter`, the label will be taken from its parent component (e.g. Activity or Application). In your case, the label of the nearest parent component is `"Money"`.

Comment: What do you mean by "Why is my app name "Money" instead of "My Ppplication"" Where is it showing this? In the launcher of phone or it is showing as Activity's Title in title bar?

Comment: Ok, but despite label in intent filter it seems like it's using the name from Activity

Comment: @Michael Do you know how should I fix this?

Comment: I'm having the same problem in current android studio: `Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 3`

Answer (score 0):

in your values/strings.xml  change

```
<string name="app_name">Money</string>
```

to

```
<string name="app_name">My Application</string>
```

Comment: Well, it’s already set like that. Check the screenshot that I’ve included

Answer (score 0):

Try this.....

```
 <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.money.list.MoneyActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"/>

        <activity-alias
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/main_activity_title"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:targetActivity=".activities.money.list.MoneyActivity">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>
 </application>
```